# Approximating longest cycle in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, computation-theory, operations-research

Finding the longest cycle (By cycle I mean cycle with no node repitition) in a directed graph is an NP-hard problem, otherwise we can tell if the graph is Hamiltonian or not. My question is: Is there any alpha-approxiamtion polynomial algorithm for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the longest directed path problem in a directed graph cannot be approximated in polynomial time within a factor of `n^(1-epsilon)` for any `epsilon > 0`, we can quickly deduce that it is also the case for the longest cycle in a directed graph unless P=NP ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Approximation)).

You can make the reduction as follows:
Choose a vertex `v`, duplicate `v` into `v1` and `v2`, duplicate all concerned arcs as well. Now find the longest directed path from `v1` to `v2`.
Do that for all vertices in the graph. That gives you the longest directed cycle in the graph.

Conclusion: there is no `alpha`-approximation in polynomial time for the longest cycle problem in directed graphs (unless P=NP of course).